# Magento 1.9 deleting 2 products consequently from mini cart shows an error : 'Invalid form key'

Tags: magento

I am using Magento 1.9.
I am facing issue in deleting product from mini cart.
Removing single product from minicart works proper.But when I try to remove another product  without reloading page.It shows following error : 
Invalid form key

Trace:

```
**#0 /var/sites/l/xyz.com/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(604): Mage::throwException('Invalid form ke...')
#1 /var/sites/l/xyz.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_CartController->ajaxDeleteAction()
#2 /var/sites/l/xyz.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('ajaxDelete')
#3 /var/sites/l/xyz.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#4 /var/sites/l/xyz.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#5 /var/sites/l/xyz.com/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#6 /var/sites/l/xyz.com/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#7 {main}**
```

Anyone can help will great.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you happen to have any tracking software implemented in your site? This same issue was occurring for me, and it turned out that Adobe's Dynamic Tag Manager was what was actually causing the issue. Adobe DTM was performing a GET request on the "Remove Item" hyperlink. Our SEO team had to modify the tracking rules on their end, instructing Adobe DTM to not target that specific link.

Answer (score 0):

Since Magento 1.8 all the forms need an formkey.

First you hat to check with developer-tools if there any forms without an formkey while deleting from mini cart.

If there, go to your IDE and search for this position in your templates (maybe the form has an id or an class which will be helpfull to identify the correct template.

Add the formkey after opening -Tag eith this line:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
```

hope that helps!

Comment: Hi,yes can you please tell where is the file containing form for this minicart? I serached but can not find.Please help .Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using MAgento 1.9.0.1 I had the same problem after increasing the following PHP settings (`php.ini`) for doing imports:

**Error cause:**

```
post_max_size = 128M
```

as suggested in some articles about import...

After setting them back to default (64M)

**Solution:**

```
post_max_size = 64M
```

and ,naturally, deleting all the cache folders under `/var/cache/`, everything went back to normal.

Comment: it doesnt make sense that the problem getting resolved after decreasing the post_max_size, do you know the reason?

Comment: @leo Unfortunately not. If I'm getting to know, I'll post it, ok?

Answer (score 0):

For that above issue,kindly follow below steps:
1.open the below file

app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml

change the below line 157 like this:

```
  <a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart/ajaxDelete',array('id'=>$this->getItem()->getId(),Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED => Mage::helper('core/url')->getEncodedUrl(),'form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey())); ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Remove This Item')) ?>"
               data-confirm="<?php echo $this->__('Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?') ?>"
               class="remove">
                <?php echo $this->__('Remove Item') ?>
            </a>
```

now refresh the cart page and also confirm with no jquery issues are there in cart page then work properly at cart page.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the form key.

The mini cart `ajaxDelete` function is not getting the form key. We can resolve the issue by removing the form key check.

Goto `/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers`, open `CartController.php` and find the function `ajaxDeleteAction()`.

In the function you will see:

```
 if(!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
       Mage::throwException('Invalid form key');
 }
```

Remove this line of code, and try to check the cart delete action.
It will work properly now.